# Aiohttp: Server & Client in one time

Tags: python-asyncio, aiohttp

I try to use aiohttp 3.6.2 both server and client:
For webhook perform work:

1) Get JSON-request from service
2) Fast send HTTP 200 OK back to service
3) Made additional work after: make http-request to slow web-service(answer 2-5 sec)

I dont understand how to perform work after view(or handler) returned web.Response(text="OK")?

Current view:
(it's slow cause slow http_request perform before response)
view.py:

```py
async def make_http_request(url):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.get(url) as resp:
            print(await resp.text())

async def work_on_request(request):
    url = (await request.json())['url']
    await make_http_request(url)
    return aiohttp.web.Response(text='all ok')
```

routes.py:

```
from views import work_on_request

def setup_routes(app):
    app.router.add_get('/', work_on_request)
```

server.py:

```
from aiohttp import web
from routes import setup_routes
import asyncio


app = web.Application()
setup_routes(app)
web.run_app(app)
```

So, workaround for me is to start one more thread with different event_loop, or may be you know how to add some work to current event loop?

Answer (score 0):

Already not actual, cause i found desicion to add one more task to main event_loop:
//additionaly i created one global queue to interoperate coroutine between each other.

```py
loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
queue = asyncio.Queue(maxsize=100000)

loop.create_task(worker('Worker1', queue))
app = web.Application()
app['global_queue'] = queue
```